# Spring MVC, how to generate temporary link

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application which uses Spring MVC. Is it possible that controller return temporary view depending on condition ? For example

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String home(){
    // some code here
       return "home/{RANDOM_HASH}" 
}
```

and user is redirected to this link. There is some action and when it finishes, he will be redirected somewhere else and he will not be able to connect to this even if he write full path, including random hash.
English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `@PathVariable` to bind HTTP parameters to method arguments:

```
@RequestMapping(value="home/{hash}")
public String link(@PathVariable String hash) {
    // 1) verify hash was not made up
    // 2) do whatever needs done with hash
    return "somewhereElse";
}
```

As to *how* to verify the hash was really created by your application and not typed in the URL bar: you can create some sort of "token manager". It would manage all hashes: issue new tokens and invalidate old ones once they're used. Simplified implementation could be something like this:

```
@NotThreadSafe
class TokenService {
    private final Set<String> hashes = new HashSet<String>();

    public String getHash() {
        String hash = "???"; // TODO: random generator
        hashes.put(hash);
        return hash;
    }

    public void invalidateHash(String hash) {
        hashes.remove(hash);
    }

    public boolean checkHash(String hash) {
        return hashes.contains(hash);
    }
}
```

Please note that real-life implementation should make access to `hashes` thread-safe.